# Testing event registration

Tags: civievent, registration

I've created an event and I'd like to test my registration forms. I go to Event Manager and select the "Test drive" link. The registration page won't display. 
I get error "The event you requested is currently unavailable (contact the site administrator for assistance)."
I suspect it is because the event is disabled. However, if I enable the event, users can see it. That sort of makes the ability to test it useless.
Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to test a disabled event registration?
Thans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the event needs to be active to use the test drive.

If you have an event listing page, you can uncheck Public event. That way users only see the event if you create a link to it. You should be safe in temporarily making it active for testing.