# How can I preview the event info of a non-active event?

Tags: civievent, permissions, acl

To ensure that the event information page looks as I want, I'd like to preview it before I activate the event.

When I do that I get a "no authorization" with a big fat 0 (zero). I'm running Joomla so I don't know if that is a Joomla error or not.

I've looked through the ACL-settings and there seems to be no "view non-active" operation that could affect this.

Is this possible somehow or do I have to activate, preview and deactivate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the event needs to be active to use (preview) it.

If you have an event listing page, you can uncheck Public event. That way users only see the event if you create a link to it. You should be safe in temporarily making it active for testing.

This is the same Question/Answer as: [Testing event registration](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/testing-event-registration/7727)